# Can't get the Meta Data of a MP3 to Write to a test box any ideas?

Tags: c++, qt, mp3, metadata, avaudioplayer

Does anyone know why I am not able to get the metaData of the song name to display in the text box, I have tried everything.

```
  void Widget::on_SongName_objectNameChanged(const QString)
   {
   QString SongName = player->metaData("SongName").toString();
   textset->setText(SongName);
   }
```

Its currently recognising song and playing them, I just want to be able to output the information. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because this key is not handled by `QMediaPlayer`.

See documentation for full list of [supported properties](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/qmediametadata.html)

I think you should have more chance with `Title` metadata property.